# How to block Users for backup?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, backup, blocking, multiple-users

I have Windows 10.

I'm using "iDrive" to backup 600GB to an external hard drive (4TB) using USB 2.0.
Last time estimate it gave me was over 24 hours.

I need to block all my family (3 other users) from using the computer until the backup is finished.

My son also uses Steam remotely over the WiFi.

I will also settle on how to make the backup continue whether people are logged in or not (the backup is started in my account). (I'm performing a full backup of the C: drive, for the first time.)

How do I block other people from using the computer until the backup is finished?

Comment: I'd like to do this for backing up to the cloud.  Backup to the cloud was taking days so I switched to using an external hard drive.

Comment: Note that backup to the cloud is a good *second* way to store data, but the external HDD is always available and under your control, as opposed to cloud services that occasionally are hacked or unavailable.

Comment: I want to make a clone of all the apps and stuff.  My understanding is that I can backup the "changes" after the full backup is completed.

Comment: Should I switch to cloning the drive instead?